# Выборка значений из списка

Tags: python, arcgis

как прописать чтобы при каждом прохождении цикла из списка выбиралось новое значение ? В данном варианте при прохождении цикла из списка берется первое значение `lyr.name=l[0]` а нужно чтобы каждый раз там было следующее т.е `lyr.name=l[1]`, `lyr.name=l[2]` и тк. К сожалению мои знания по питону оч малы так что прошу сильно не пинать :)

```py
l=[] #список
n = 0
while n!=8:
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("...")
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
    for lyr in targetGroupLayer:
        if lyr.name!="New Group Layer":
            lyr.name=l[0]
    n=n+1
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: у вас индекс в l постоянно 0 будет. Наверное стоит в `lyr.name=l[0]` передавать вместо 0 n

Comment: отступы подправьте. И заголовок заодно.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin к сожалению не помогло, в данном случаи просто перебираются значения и последнее значение в списке присваивается объекту

Comment: @Grechkin26 Не нужно писать свой ответ в текст вопроса. Оформите его отдельным ответом. К тому же ваш "до боли простой" ответ как-то не сильно коррелирует с вопросом. Ну или не понятно, как добавление дополнительных условий дает возможность обращения к элементам списка

Answer (score 2):

Прохождение циклом по списку в питоне можно реализовать несколькими способами:

Пусть у нас имеется список:

```py
lst = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

1. Получение элементов списка в качестве значения счетчика:

```py
for el in lst:
    print(el)
# вывод:
# one
# two
# three
```

2. Получение в счетчике индекса элемента:

```py
# здесь len(lst) возвращает количество элементов в списке, 
# а range() возвращает итерируемый объект, содержащий 
# ряд чисел от 0 до указанного максимума.
for i in range(len(lst)): 
    print(i, lst[i])
# вывод:
# 0 one
# 1 two
# 2 three
```

3. Получение пары индекса и элемента через функцию `enumerate()`

```py
for i, v in enumerate(lst):
    print(i, v)
# вывод:
# 0 one
# 1 two
# 2 three
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ оказался до боли прост

```py
l=[] #список
n = 0
while n!=8:
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("...")
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
    for lyr in targetGroupLayer:
        if lyr.name!="New Group Layer":
            if lyr.name=="...":    # необходимо добавить доп условие которое исключает уже переименованные на предыдущем цикле объекты
                lyr.name=l[n] # вместо lyr.name=l[0] нужно ставить lyr.name=l[n]
    n=n+1
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```